# how to declare a function globally in the iphone application

Tags: iphone

I know how to make global variables in the iphone programing. I want to know can we make a global function in iphone application (like a global veriables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do so, global functions are not a good idea when programming in Objective C , you should read later the basic ideas of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)

Nevertheless, there is a good and easy way to achieve what you are trying to do, without doing a major programming sin.

in your ApplicationDelegate file declare your function
for example:

```
// In the Delegate M
-(void)GlobalFunction
{
    NSLog(@"A global function was called);
}
```

from another viewController / Class or such do this:

```
yourApplicationNameDelegate *appDelegate = (DPRAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate GlobalFunction];
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution for making Global Function is to declare a function in AppDelegate Class.
Access it classes required.

```
// AppDelegate.h 
-(void) someFunction;

// AppDelegate.m
-(void) someFunction {    // Function body

}

// Import in header file of a class where global function is to be accessed
#import AppDelegate.h 

// Implementation file of a class where global function is to be accessed
 [((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) someFunction];
```